# How to make JDBC SQLExceptions for DB2 more descriptive?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, error-handling, db2

How to make SQLExceptions thrown by DB2 JDBC driver more descriptive?

Currently I am getting this kind of exceptions. It is cumbersome to work with these cryptic SQLCODE and SQLSTATE numeric values. Is there a way where to make the SQL exception to contain code description.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, 
     SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.c(hh.java:1662)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.a(hh.java:1238)
      at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.db.n(db.java:737) 
      ....
```

e.g. SQLSTATE 22001 has this description:

> Character data, right truncation occurred; for example, an update or insert value is a string that is too long for the column, or a datetime value cannot be assigned to a host variable, because it is too small.

Edit: I am also using Spring and Hibernate frameworks.

Comment: It would be great to check the solution for your question :-)

Answer (score 23):

Set the JDBC driver property `retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage` to `true`. Example connection url:

```
jdbc:db2://host:50128/MYDB:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;
```

See also [DB2 11.1 Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvjcerr.html)

Comment: Great. Saved my day!

Comment: This works for much older DB2 also. Don't forget the ";" at the end.

Answer (score 11):

1. Check that the exception implements `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable`
2. On a `DB2Diagnosable`, you can call `getSqlca()` to get a `DB2Sqlca`. It will return the SQL error code (`getSqlCode()`), the state (`getSqlState()`) and you can call `getMessage()` to get a properly formatted and readable error message.

There is probably a smart reason why IBM didn't map this to `getMessage()` of the exception. My guess is that they didn't because `DB2Sqlca.getMessage()` can throw nasty exceptions, so you must wrap it in `try-catch`.

Answer (score 3):

Spring contains [translators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.html) for SQLException which convert the database-specific codes and states into a description exception class hierarchy.

It's part of the larger Spring API, but there's nothing stopping you from using just that class.

---

For example, if you have a DAO which extends `JdbcDaoSupport`, then you can have code like this:

```
try {
   // ... some code that throws SQLException
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   throw getExceptionTranslator().translate(null, null, ex);
}
```

This translates and wraps the `SQLException` is Spring's own strongly typed exception hierarchy.

If you're not using `JdbcDaoSupport`, then you can use the `getExceptionTranslator()` method of `JdbcTemplate` (and if you're not using that, then look at the source to see how it works.)